# Launching an Air Application from the browser

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air

I am working on integrating an air application with a web application and for the most part it works.

The only issue that I am having is that when I attempt to pass variables from my launching badge, the application does not load and I get no errors from my swf.

Here is my current code base:

Launching Badge AS:

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.system.*;
import flash.text.TextField;

// AIRBadge is our main document class
public class LaunchApplication extends MovieClip {

    public function LaunchApplication() {

        _loader = new Loader();
        var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
        loaderContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onInit);
        _loader.load(new URLRequest(BROWSERAPI_URL_BASE + "/air.swf"), loaderContext);

        var parameters:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
        _applicationID = parameters["applicationID"];
        _arguments = String(parameters["arguments"]).split(",");

    }

    private function onInit(e:Event):void {
        _air = e.target.content;
        switch (_air.getStatus()) {
            case "installed" :
                statusMessage.text = "AIR is installed and has been detected."
                launchButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onButtonClicked);
                break;
            case "available" :
                // AIR is Available
                statusMessage.text = "AIR is not installed - application cannot be launched."
                break;
            case "unavailable" :
                // AIR Not Available
                statusMessage.text = "AIR is not installed - application cannot be launched."
                break;
        }
    }

    private function onButtonClicked(e:Event):void {

        statusMessage.text = "Attempting to Launch AIR Application";
        trace(_applicationID);
        _air.launchApplication(_applicationID,_arguments);

    }

    private const BROWSERAPI_URL_BASE: String = "http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi";

    private var _applicationID:String;
    private var _arguments: Array;

    private var _loader:Loader;
    private var _air:Object;

}
```

}

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("launchMovie.swf", "badge", "250", "75", "9.0.115", "#FFFFFF");
so.addVariable( "applicationID", "com.testapp.test");
so.addVariable( "arguments", "123");
so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the *-app.xml file in your AIR project and set  to true?